createMediaElementSource doesnt accept audio element - parameter is not of type 'HTMLMediaElement'
I am trying to analyze remote wav file contents. Sound plays fine, but if I want to analyze it, I keep getting error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLMediaElement'.
Why doesnt createMediaElementSource accepot the snd element and complains is beyond me...
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://172.20.132.65/saved_wav/save/240824_200345.wav", true);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  xhr.onload = function () {
          if (this.status === 200) {      

            var Sound = (function () {
                var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
                return function Sound(src) {
                        var snd = new Audio(src);
                        df.appendChild(snd); // keep in fragment until finished playing
                        snd.addEventListener('ended', function () {df.removeChild(snd);});
                        snd.play();

                        let input = self.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(snd);
                        let analyser = self.audioContext.createAnalyser();
                                                                                                                                                                               analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0;
                         analyser.fftSize = self.fftsize;
                         input.connect(analyser);
                         self.analyser = analyser;
                         self.freq = new Uint8Array(self.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                         self.render();

                        return snd;
                    }
            }());
              
            var snd = Sound("data:audio/wav;base64," + window.btoa(self.arrayBufferToBin(xhr.response)));

        }
  };
  xhr.send();


Wondering if that could have to do with that you are appending the audio element to a DocumentFragment? Does anything change, if you append it to the current document directly?

@C3roe same error...

@C3roe sound plays fine as stated above

Any change if you use var snd = document.createElement('audio'); snd.src = src; instead of var snd = new Audio(src); (They should have pretty much the same effect though, but it might be worth a try.)

@C3roe tried it when searching for solution numerous times - same error

Could snd.addEventListener('ended', function () {df.removeChild(snd);}); be at fault perhaps? (Not sure how long your wav file is, so not sure when this would trigger either.)

@C3roe commented it out, still same error
